# How to increment the ID automatically in java NetBeans using mysql and to insert the current year or date inside the ID

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, increment

hello evryone am working a **student management system** and for saving students information in mysql
database am using an auto-increment but i want make all StudentID to start with "ST"  followed by the "Currentyear"
then a number that will be incremented automaticly and be didplayed in a jTextField i have designed and named "jTextFieldstudentid"
the probeme is when i  run the file, the output is not corresponding to what i need, in the students Table on mysql dB the last ID = "ST2020001"
but in the jTextField am getting "ST20200012020002" instead of "ST2020002" please help, i dont know if there is something wrong with my code.

````
private void StudentAutoID()
     {
         try {
            String sql="SELECT StudentID FROM students ORDER BY StudentID DESC LIMIT 1";       
            PreparedStatement  pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
                {
                Date d=new Date();
                int year=d.getYear();
                int currentYear = year+1900;
                String rnno=rs.getString("StudentID");
                int co=rnno.length();
                String txt= rnno.substring(0, 2);
                String num=rnno.substring(2, co);
                int n=Integer.parseInt(num);
                n++;
                String snum=Integer.toString(n);
                String ftxt=txt+currentYear+snum;
                jTextFieldstudentid.setText(ftxt);

                }
            else
                {
                jTextFieldstudentid.setText("ST2020000");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
            }

     }```
````

Comment: Not a good strategy to use such an ID structure! A simple _"StudentID"_ column of type _BIGINT(20)_ and _auto incremented_ (and _NOT NULL_) would be the perfect choice. The specific details regarding each student can then be saved in other columns.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```java
String num=rnno.substring(2, co);
```

Your substring includes the year as well.

If you change it to:

```java
String num=rnno.substring(6, co);
```

it will work as expected.

However, I would reconsider the model. It might be better to keep atomic fields for a year and a numerical id; and based on those fields to calculate the student id in the java code without the invocations of the substring method.

Comment: This worked actually, thank you Patrycja Wegrzynowicz,  I choose this method to get some information regarding the student just by watching the ID.